# Error message when loading VS Code Unable to resolve your shell environment: A system error occured(spawn/user/bin/zsh ENOENT

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, zsh

Hi I am running Ubuntu 20.04 I used to have zsh installed and oh-my-zsh I have uninstalled them both and now when I start vs code using the GUI from my Desktop I receive the following error message with screenshot below

Unable to resolve your shell environment: A system error occured(spawn/user/bin/zsh ENOENT

[Screenshot when VS Code Loads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFlEj.png)

I have gone into the settings for vs code in default profile for linux and have set it to bash

[default profile linux set to bash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ceR4.png)

when I open up vs code from the terminal by running the command code . I do not receive this error since I am in a bash terminal.  I have been looking around all over to find where does vs code look for a .zsh path when loading from the GUI.  thank you.

Edit: here is my settings.json

```
{
  "terminal.integrated.tabs.enabled": true,
  "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
  "files.insertFinalNewline": true,
  "files.trimFinalNewlines": true,
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
  },
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "chrome",
  "update.mode": "none",
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "liveServer.settings.host": "localhost",
  "window.zoomLevel": 3,
  "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
  "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
  "terminal.integrated.automationProfile.linux": {

  },
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "bash",
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
    
    "bash": {
      "path": "bash",
      "icon": "terminal-bash"
    },
    "fish": {
      "path": "fish"
    },
    "tmux": {
      "path": "tmux",
      "icon": "terminal-tmux"
    },
    "pwsh": {
      "path": "pwsh",
      "icon": "terminal-powershell"
    }
  },
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": ""
}
```

also included a error message I am getting for line 21 at

```
"terminal.integrated.automationProfile.linux": {

  },
```

[error message on line 21](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZ1gp.png)

[line 20 through 21 has mark for error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D53WT.png)

Comment: Can you post your settings JSON ?

Comment: @TimothyG. thank you for the response I have edited my post to include the settings.JSON from vs code.

Comment: SOLVED:  

` sudo chsh -s /usr/bin/bash`

then when I check what is my shell by running 

`echo $SHELL`

The error is no longer appearing.

Comment: Credit to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/139867#issuecomment-1006220359

Comment: `$SHELL` changed for me after editing the shell path directly in the `etc/passwd` file for my user. `chsh -s` or `usermod -s` didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [this vscode issue comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/139867#issuecomment-1006220359):

```
sudo chsh -s /usr/bin/bash
```

then when I check what is my shell by running

```
echo $SHELL
```

it now points to `/usr/bin/bash`

The error is no longer appearing when launching VS Code from GUI.

Comment: In my case, `/usr/bin/bash` should be changed to `/bin/bash`

Answer (score 2):

if this is your [issue](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq#_resolving-shell-environment-fails)

Changing the desktop file of vs code like this, worked for me!:

```bash
    #Exec=/usr/share/code/code --unity-launch %F
    Exec=/usr/bin/code
```

> you may need to figure out where the desktop file stored depending on
> how you installed vs code.

Answer (score 1):

simple solution of the above error! is to again install the zsh
using:  sudo apt install zsh -y
no need to do anything just restart the Vs code after running the above code in your command bash.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue.

I ended up solving the issue by creating a symbolic link from the path VS Code is checking (`/usr/local/bin/zsh` in my case) to the zsh path (the path you see when you run `which zsh`. It was `/opt/homebrew/bin/zsh` in my case).

So I ran the following command and it worked.
`sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/zsh /usr/local/bin/zsh`

Answer (score 0):

The process outlined below may help you identify which parts of your shell initialization are taking the most time:

- Open your shell's startup file (for example, in VS Code by typing
  ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc in Quick Open (⌘P)).
- Selectively comment out potentially long running operations (such as
  nvm if you find that).
- Save and fully restart VS Code.
- Continue commenting out operations until the error disappears.

**Worked for me**

[Source](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq#_investigate-slow-shell-initialization)